# How can Schrenk approximation be used to model lift load on a rectangular wing?

Tags: wing, flight-training, ultralight, airplane

How can I use Schrenk approximation to calculate load distribution on my rectangular wing?
A worked example will be appreciated.

Comment: NASA has a report on it: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930094469.pdf